# Using JavaScript how can I break a string at a certain length, preserving special characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a block of text:

```
George wanted to bake cookies. He asked Mom to help him.

George decided he would bake chocolate-chip cookies. First, Mom had to buy the ingredients. She bought flour, sugar, and chocolate chips. Next, George and Mom mixed together all the ingredients. Finally, they put the cookies in the oven for ten minutes. Last, they let the cookies cool down, and ate them.

"These are delicious!" said George.
```

I want to convert this to an array with lines of up to 50 characters each.

I have currently:

```
var lines = text.split(/\r|\n/g);
lines.forEach(function (item, index) {
  words = item.match(/.{1,50}\b/g);
});
```

This almost works, but it ignores periods and things like that, so I'm left with

```
George wanted to bake cookies. He asked Mom to
help him

George decided he would bake chocolate-chip
cookies. First, Mom had to buy the ingredients.
She bought flour, sugar, and chocolate chips. Next
, George and Mom mixed together all the
ingredients. Finally, they put the cookies in the
oven for ten minutes. Last, they let the cookies
cool down, and ate them

"These are delicious!" said George.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: what does `\b` match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spaces instead of word boundaries (that matches between a letter and a dot):

For example with this pattern:

```
/\S(?:.{0,48}\S)?(?!\S)/g
```

details:

```
\S              # all that is not a white-space
(?:.{0,48}\S)?  # between 0 and 48 characters followed by a non white character
(?!\S)          # not followed by a non-white character (in other words, followed
                # by a white space or the end of the string)
```

The other advantage is that the pattern avoids leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `g` the global modifier. Which returns all the matches, not just the first one. You seem to need the first 50 characters only. The anchor `b` will keep the the last word not broken and hence actual string might be less than 50 characters. This should give you the proper result:

```
var lines = text.split(/\r|\n/g);
lines.forEach(function (item, index) {
  words = item.match(/.{1,50}\b/);
  alert(words);
});
```

You'll have to modify further considering if you want to keep spaces and punctuations out of count.